Flutter Application not login in on physical device but login in on emulator
I am creating a flutter application that works well on my emulator but when I run an apk, it can't login. It logs in on my emulator perfectly. What might be the issue?
I have tried login in on the apk but it's not working.

Which method and framework login are you using?
If it is Google login with firebase, go to firebase dashboard and check whether you added sha fingerprint for release keystore (which signs your apk)
Because when you run project through IDE, it uses debug keystore to sign your app (which maybe was added), but when you build an apk, it uses release keystore (which not yet)


Thankyou, my issue was that I had not added
 in my android.manifest.xml file
